# Is there a function in R to partially match a row in a column to 2 columns in a different data set and add a Y N column to the first dataset?

Tags: r, logical-operators, partial-matches

I have 2 data sets, say A and B, I want to add a column to A that has Y or N on weather A$4 matches B$5 and or B$6.

I tried

```
A %>%
 add_column(Match = ifelse(A$4 %in% c(B$5, B$6), Y, N))
```

However B$5 and B$6 sometimes contain multiple options, separated by a comma.

For example, if a value in A$4 is (CR2), and a value in B$5 is (CR6) and B$6 is (CR1,CR2), I still want the A$Match to be Y. And using the %in% operator only gives Y for an exact match.

Comment: Is A,B a vector, list or data frame? Can you show how these datasets are constructed in R?

Comment: Both A and B are dataframes, A contains 100 observations of 10 variables and B 1000 or so observations of 38 variables, I have since fixed the issue using the loop mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting some help from a collegue, since the datasets arent too big we opted to loop through the data.

```
Match_list <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(file_A)) {
  print(file_A[i,4])
  if (any(mapply(grepl, file_A[i,4], fileB$5))) {
    Match_list <- append(Match_list, "Y")
  } else if (any(mapply(grepl, file_A[i,4], fileB$6))) {
    Match_list <- append(Match_list, "Y")
  } else {
    Match_list <- append(Match_list, "N")
  }
}
file_A['Match'] <- Match_list
```